# Function updating multiple columns in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a table i want to update:

```
q)show table:([]letter:`a`b`c`a;fruit:`apple`banana`pear`strawberry;family:`mom`dad`brother`sister)
letter fruit      family
-------------------------
a      apple      mom
b      banana     dad
c      pear       brother
a      strawberry sister
```

I want to replace all entries with the name of their respective column.

This seems to work:

```
q){![table;();0b;(enlist x)!(enlist `x)]}`letter
letter fruit      family
-------------------------
letter apple      mom
letter banana     dad
letter pear       brother
letter strawberry sister
```

...but not this:

```
q){![table;();0b;(enlist x)!(enlist `x)]}`letter`fruit
'type
  [1]  {![table;();0b;(enlist x)!(enlist `x)]}
        ^
q))
```

The purpose is to create a function that creates dummy variables for categorical variables, so I need a general function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved with `@ apply` instead of a functional update like so:

```
q){@[`table;x;:;x]}`letter`fruit
`table
q)table
letter fruit family
--------------------
letter fruit mom
letter fruit dad
letter fruit brother
letter fruit sister
```

Edit - For all cols:

```
{@[`table;x;:;x]} each cols table
```

or

```
{@[x;y;:;y]}/[table;cols table]

q)table
letter fruit family
-------------------
letter fruit family
letter fruit family
letter fruit family
letter fruit family
```

Comment: I need a generalization, useable for any table without plugging in specific column names. is there a way to make this work? {@[`table;x;:;x]}cols table

Answer (score 2):

Your original functional update could work like this:

```
q){![table;();0b;x!enlist'[x:(),x]]}cols table
letter fruit family
-------------------
letter fruit family
letter fruit family
letter fruit family
letter fruit family
```